# FakeRequest Result of type Promise

Tags: java, junit, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I need to test an API written in Java with Play Framework v2.1.1
Considering the test below, it passes (isNotNull) but I cannot check if I get the correct result (i.e. status code, JSON array in the response, ...). It works with any call, even if the route doesn't actually exist.
The Logger logs the following: `AsyncResult(scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@3c7feca8`
Does that mean that the result is still to come, if yes: how do I get it?

```
@Test
public void testRoute() {
    Result result = routeAndCall(fakeRequest(GET, "/api/call"));
    assertThat(result).isNotNull();
    Logger.info(result.toString());
}
```

Grateful for any reply! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Helpers](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.1/java/play/test/Helpers.html) class:

```
import static play.test.Helpers.*; //important import

@Test
public void testRoute() {
    Result result = routeAndCall(fakeRequest(GET, "/api/call"));
    assertThat(result).isNotNull();
    assertThat(status(result)).isEqualTo(200);
    assertThat(getContentAsString(result)).isEqualTo("{\"a\": [1,2,3,4,5]}");
}
```